# Issues with LUA copy

Tags: lua

I am using the following program to copy one file another. I am often seeing source and destination is not exactly the same (md5sum is different). Are there anything wrong with the below code?

```
local size = 2^13      -- good buffer size (8K)

local params = {...}
local srcfile = params[1]
local outfile = params[1] .. "_copy"

print (srcfile)
print (outfile)


local inf = io.open(srcfile, "r")
local of = io.open(outfile, "w")

while true do
    local block = inf:read(size)
    print(size)
    if not block then break end
       of:write(block)
end

inf:close()
of:close()
```

Thanks,
GL

Comment: Discard the loop and use just `of:write(inf:read("*a"))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use binary mode to ensure endline characters were not modified.

```
local inf = io.open(srcfile, "rb")
local of = io.open(outfile, "wb")
```

Comment: You'll have to show example of data that gets broken. Using binary mode in io.open is critical on windows, and your sample is working ok for me after adding "b" to file open mode.

Comment: A totally different problem. Not related to LUA